# Free file storage, working as Git/GitHub, Windows, portable

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-storage, portable

I work with git/GitHub and Bazaar/Launchpad. But on GitHub and Launchpad it is impossible to store the files which aren't relating to my projects and on these services not enough room for files is free of charge made. Please, advise the storage services meeting the following conditions:

- Free 15 GB or more for files;
- File synchronization;
- Sync any folder, not just the one in which synchronization program files are located;
- Support Windows, Windows XP inclusive;
- Portable version client (for example, SpiderOak is not portable);
- Share files for all unlimited time period (for example, hubiC [not support](https://hubic.com/en/sharing));

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [MEGA](https://mega.nz/):

- 50GB free
- Can synchronize files through MEGAsync (you can copy the MEGAsync from `%appdata%` to your USB-stick)
- You can share files

Comment: Thank you, I am now testing this service, Mega I liked more than [*other alternatives*](http://alternativeto.net/software/dropbox/). But I haven't figured out how to sync with the cloud storage folders and files that are not in the MegaSync folder without copying the folders and files in the MegaSync folder.

Comment: I thought that was possible the last time I used it... I'll check it soon...

Comment: And Mega don't have online viewer for documents in text formats. For example, my book in [**Mega**](https://mega.nz/#!hRBjjJaA!LKxCGwpnI2o8oUtAzyEQP85mtm9N2pGvOOzm9ma8aiM) and [**Zoho Docs**](https://docs.zoho.com/file/9ustl0ebab1b5e94745b6a5cc656051b3e8d0).

Comment: But you haven't asked for that in the question...

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks for the answer!